# Reuse error message from `thiserror` definition

Tags: rust, thiserror

I use [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) crate for error handling inside my project.

I declare an error like this

```rs
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error)]
enum CustomErrors {
    #[error("This is custom error one")]
    CustomErrorOne,

    #[error("This is custom error two")]
    CustomErrorTwo
}
```

I use this custom error like this

```rs
// cut

match foo() {
  Err(errors) -> match errors {
     CustomErrors::CustomErrorOne => ..., // I want to get access to "This is custom error one" error message here
     CustomErrors::CustomErrorTwo => ..., // ...and here
  }
}

//cut
```

Am I understanding correctly that this is not possible due to the philosophy of the `thiserror`? And it requires creating a new error message?

> Thiserror deliberately does not appear in your public API. (c) [Documentation](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror#details)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.rs/thiserror/1.0.32/thiserror/#details):

> A `Display` impl is generated for your error if you provide `#[error("...")]` messages on the struct or each variant of your enum...

So if you want to get that string from the `CustomErrors`, you just need to call `.to_string()`.

Comment: Could you provide an example using my code snippet from the question? Intuitively, I want to do something like this. `match errors { CustomErrors::CustomErrorOne => CustomErrors::CustomErrorOne.to_string()`. But it doesn't work

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi not sure what you're doing since that code works, though it can be simpler. [See this playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fab21afe8414be0202847cbf5c8900e3).

Comment: My bad. I relied on the IntelliSense tooltip that didn't show me the suggestion option for `to_string()`. Therefore, I made the conclusion that this will not work. Thank you.