# What does this #[error(...)] line do in an error type?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I am currently using the official mongodb driver for rust and while looking at error type for mongodb I came across this line in the `mongodb::error::Error` implementation:

```rust
#[error("Kind: {kind}, labels: {labels:?}")]
```

What is the meaning of this line? What functionality does it add to the struct?

the `mongodb::error::Error`struct is defined as follows:

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Error)]
#[error("Kind: {kind}, labels: {labels:?}")]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub struct Error {
    /// The type of error that occurred.
    pub kind: Box<ErrorKind>,
    labels: HashSet<String>,
    pub(crate) wire_version: Option<i32>,
    #[source]
    pub(crate) source: Option<Box<Error>>,
}
```

Source : [here](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/src/mongodb/error.rs.html#45-52)

Comment: This line is not part of Rust itself. It is interpreted by the [`thiserror` crate](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) when deriving `Error`. See [the `thiserror` docs](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The line `#[error("Kind: {kind}, labels: {labels:?}")]` is a parameter that influences the `#[derive(Error)]` one line above.

It specifies how the error can be printed; to be specific, it implements `Display` for the struct.

See [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=92713b06c2276d4dc98ffc52bccf1f91):

```rust
use thiserror::Error;
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Error)]
#[error("Kind: {kind}, labels: {labels:?}")]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub struct Error {
    kind: String,
    labels: HashSet<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let my_error = Error {
        kind: "SpecialKind".to_string(),
        labels: HashSet::from([
            "xyz".to_string(),
            "aaa".to_string()
        ])
    };
    
    println!("{}", my_error);
}
```

```
Kind: SpecialKind, labels: {"xyz", "aaa"}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is the *error message* attribute from [`thiserror`](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/). They enable you to construct implementations of the `std::error::Error` trait with custom messages in an easier way that by hand. You can see further above the linked line that the [`Error`](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/derive.Error.html) derive macro was imported in [line 11](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/src/mongodb/error.rs.html#11).

The linked example applies the attribute macro on a struct type, but it can also be used on enum variants. Another example on the use of this derive macro can be seen from the documentation itself.

```
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum DataStoreError {
    #[error("data store disconnected")]
    Disconnect(#[from] io::Error),
    #[error("the data for key `{0}` is not available")]
    Redaction(String),
    #[error("invalid header (expected {expected:?}, found {found:?})")]
    InvalidHeader {
        expected: String,
        found: String,
    },
    #[error("unknown data store error")]
    Unknown,
}
```

See also:

- [Reuse error message from `thiserror` definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240062/reuse-error-message-from-thiserror-definition)